# Prestashop 1.6 CCC css new file in cache each time

Tags: css, caching, sass, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I don't know how prestashop work. I'm a full stack developer and i need to resolve a problem in a prestashop project.

I use a theme "sns_kanta" modified by one other developper.

When i enable the css cache with the CCC options in dashboard, each time a user load a page, a compiled css file is created in cache folder in the theme. 1 page view = 1 new file.

Many time later... this give 28 GB useless data. Time passed to compile it is useless.

Anyone have an idea ? 
A start point for see where is the problem ? To debug it.

i try to check the prestashop documentation and try to see why css it's compiled each time  ...

I know it's not easy without an access and all data, but if you have an idea, a file to check, ...

Thx a lot in advance

Comment: check the theme configuration, prestashop generate one file, stop. If there was an edit in one of css file that makes the one compressed, in that case prestashop generates a new one css compressed.

Comment: Thx for the reply. I'm not sure to understand what you want to say. In theme configuration, i don't have any option for the css. Which file can be edit each time ?

Comment: Sorry, I was too vague. You have to check if the template (sns_kanta in your case) have some module that allows to you to configure "things" (colors, css inline, js inline, etc, etc)... Usually this modules is very very bad, and maybe in your case they compile the css at every page load, so, first check if there is "human-friendly" option that disable that, otherwise you have to "navigate" in the code of modules and find the guilty

Comment: I will look that. Thank for the tips. But how the CCC concat all files ? What is the process ? i don't find a link explain that. Where is the file list to compile ? Any other tips/idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an option in theme option like : -> ADVANCE SETTINGS -> SCSS Compile -> Always compile

I changed this to only if css file is not found.

useless time losed.

Thank's for the help and sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at `displayHeader()` method in `classes/controller/FrontController.php`. For each page, this method will check if `CCC` is activated and will accordingly assign one or multiple css files to the header of your page.

If `CCC` is activated, then the method `cccCss()` in `classes/controller/Media.php` is called. You can debug this method to find the file that have changed since last page load.

Comment: I have check that. I can see this function is deprecated. The website use the "display" function. I can see 3 files, 2 google fonts, and one file with the name is updated anytime : "themes/sns_kanta/cache/v_58054_eb3d90ef01782965507d90a10c5a7c8a_all.css". The key "58054" is already incremented anytime. I don't found where this file is generated....

Comment: Then you can debug `addMedia` method of `FrontController` class: `var_dump($media_uri);var_dump(debug_backtrace());` (Or using xDebug ;) )

Comment: Sorry i don't read correctly, i have found where is the problem.